# Get All Attendees of the Outlook Meeting room

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, powerapps, power-platform

In my PowerApps development, I need to retrieve all the attendees in the Outlook meeting room.

Using the Graph API, I will be able to retrieve all the user's calendar events.

But my requirement little different. I need to get based on the Meeting Room. So that I can find who are all planning to visit the meeting room.

Can anyone suggest me an idea to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Room is another mailbox, so you can get its activities and for each appointment check who the recipients are.